# Kőnig's lemma without a condition

Tags: graph-theory

Why does [Kőnig's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig's_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma) not hold if we replace the condition that every vertex has a finite degree with the condition that every vertex has an infinite degree?

Could you give a counter-example?

Comment: Have you tried to think about it?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich because we learned it doesn't, I just can't remember how we proved it

Comment: I think you might be confused about what you did in class. It is relatively easy to prove the claim in the case that you described. (much easier than  Kőnig's lemma)

Comment: Hint: $\infty>0$.